# How to get result in javascript from a WCF method returns int?

Tags: javascript, wcf

I have one method in my wcf Service class that returns `int` and I am calling this method through javascript as below:

```
//Interface for Service

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "TestService")]
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    int GetTest(int A,int B);
}

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class TestService : ITestService
{
   public int GetTest(a,b)
   {
     return a + b;
   }
}
```

Calling the service in javascript goes like this:

```
TestService.ITestService.GetTest(a,b,returnId);

//method to get result id in javascript
function returnId(result)
{
   alert('Result :' + result);
}
```

Now here in alert everytime I am getting this result as `null`, why? Even I changed that `int` to `List<int>` and tried but getting the result as `null`.

and this is working fine on FireFox and other browser but not working on IE. Even use fiddler to find issue and in fiddler it is giving Content-Length mismatch error. but getting the Service method value in fiddler.
Can anyone please help me why the result is `null` everytime with IE?

Comment: Do you have a ScriptManager on the page with a ScriptReference to the service?  See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/wcfinjavascript.aspx for a good beginner's guide to interfacing WCF with JavaScript.